# Basic Ordinary Differential Equation Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following $3$rd order, non-linear, homogeneous differential equation:

$$y''' + ey'' + y' + (d + e)y - dy^2 = 0,$$
where $d,e$ are constants.

My questions:

1. Have I classified this differential equation correctly? (3rd order, non-linear, homogeneous with constant coefficients)
2. What is the independent variable?

I haven't done calculus/linear algebra etc.. for approximately $2$ years, and hence, my skills are rusty. I'm panicking a little, and if you could direct me to some helpful resources I would appreciate that very much.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes, it's classified correctly.
- The independent variable can be any of your choosing as y is not explicitly stated as a function of a certain variable as it is in say $ay''(x) + by'(x) + cy(x)=0$ where $x$ is the independent variable.

[Here's a link to some videos that could help refresh your memory!](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations)

---

You can go one step further and say that it's also autonomous as there is no explicit dependency on the independent variable. An example of a non-autonomous differential equation is shown below where the $x^2$ term makes the differential equation non-autonomous: $$ x^2 y''(x) + y(x) = 0 $$

Comment: Just realised that I assumed $a$ is a constant. Is it indeed a constant?

Comment: Oh that was a typo - it meant to say d, which is in fact a constant.

Comment: I've added a small addendum to my answer, talking about autonomous DEs.